# How to solve difficult resistance puzzles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

How does one solve really difficult resistance puzzles? These are presented in the form of a diagram with multiple resistances in various combinations.

I have done some puzzles by reducing the puzzle into multiple series/parallel combinations. I know about Kirchoff's laws, and how to use them.

P.S. And while you are at it, you may try solving [this incredibly hard question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18437/).

Comment: Use the Kirchhoff laws, Luke! And for that one they also expect you to do a bit of combinatorics, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are dealing with a network of finite number of resistors, try redrawing it in some form in which you'll be able to recognize the parallel or series connections.

Secondly, take a look at [Delta-Y Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) which might be really helpful in some cases.

If these fail, turn to Kirchoff's laws i.e. put a test generator between the points you're calculating the resistance and take your time solving the circuit. Sometimes, [circuit theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Circuit_theorems) might help.

Also, watch out for high degree of symmetry ( take a look at [this problem](http://www.rfcafe.com/miscellany/factoids/kirts-cogitations-256.htm) ).

The problem you posted is quite difficult and fun. It's a both maths and physics problem and that makes it even more fun. I will take a shot at it and post an answer if i succeed.

Comment: Thanks. The Delta-Y Theorem was helpful. However, I could not understand most of the wiki links. For the resistor cube Q, why is the traditional method considered lengthy? It looks as easy as the other method suggested.